# How to use "AND operator (&&)" in OQL in MAT Eclipse

Tags: java, heap-memory, jvisualvm, oql, eclipse-mat

I am working on performance tuning of a **java rmi** application and
using OQL to execute below query :

```
select tpoint.host.value.toString() from sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint tpoint
where (tpoint.host!=null && tpoint.csf!=null)
```

Above query successfully compiles on **JVisualVM** with some records followed by this error :-

> Too many results. Please, refine your query.

Same query fails to execute in **Eclipse-MAT**.

After, removing `&& tpoint.csf!=null` from the `above query`, it compiles fine in **Eclipse-MAT**. Also it takes **very less time** as compared to JVisualVM and displays all records.

I am not able to find the correct syntax for using `&& operator` in Eclipse-MAT.

Facing hard time to find good OQL refrences for **Eclipse-MAT**, good refrences are appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are syntactical diffrences between MAT-Eclipse OQL and JVisualVM OQL.

At the time of writing this answer, it is possible to write more complex queries in JVisualVM OQL (AFAIK) as compared to MAT-Eclipse.

The only drawback is, response time of JViualVM queries is very large, and response does not includes all the records.

It will be great, if MAT developers provides good documentaion of MAT OQL queries (groupby, subquery, string manipulation operators) in the help content.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of && operator, you can use '**and**' to do combined query. Seems that MAT only supports 'and' 'or' 'not', not '&&' '||' '^'.

Below is the working OQL query in MAT.

```
SELECT tpoint.host.value.toString() FROM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint tpoint WHERE ((tpoint.host != null) and (tpoint.csf != null))
```